# How to define pointer to member function in extended class

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to transfer existing project from C to C++ and, of course, I'm stuck. Problem is a pointer to the member function in extended class. So, here is example:

Basic class

```
typedef void (*fnMenuFunction)(int argc, char *argv[]);

typedef struct {
    const char      *mnuCommand;
    const char       mnuShortcut;
    fnMenuFunction   mnuFunction;
    const char      *mnuDescription;
} menuItem;

#define     UNKNOWN_COMMAND     -1
#define     TOO_MANY_ARGS       -2

class Menu {
public:
    Menu();
    virtual ~Menu();
    virtual void intMenu(void);
    int processCommand(const char * command);
    menuItem menuItems[];
private:
    int currentItem;
};
```

and new one based on Manu

```
#include "utils/Menu.h"

class CommandMenu: public Menu {
public:
    void initMenu(void);
    void CMD_showHelp(int argc, char **argv);
private:
};
```

now, when I try to define menuItem structure

```
#include "CommandMenu.h"

void CommandMenu::initMenu() {
    menuItem menuItems[] = {
        {"help", '?',     CMD_showHelp,          " : display help message" },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };
}

void CommandMenu::CMD_showHelp(int argc, char **argv) {
    // do something
}
```

I got several errors error

First, if I try to use it like this

```
menuItems[] = {
            {"help", '?',     CMD_showHelp,          " : display help message" },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };
```

I got message

> expected primary-expression before ']' token

and if I leave it as in above example

```
menuItem menuItems[] = {
    {"help", '?',     CMD_showHelp,          " : display help message" },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

I got message

> cannot convert 'CommandMenu::CMD_showHelp' from type 'void
>   (CommandMenu::)(int, char**)' to type 'const char*'

Can someone, please, explain me how this work in C++?

THX
Goran

Comment: Either make the member function `static`, or use `std::function` instead of a function pointer.

Comment: Sorry, I copy wrong error message, second one is :
cannot convert 'CommandMenu::CMD_showHelp' from type 'void (CommandMenu::)(int, char**)' to type 'fnMenuFunction {aka void (*)(int, char**)}'

Comment: Your problem is, that member function pointers are different from plain function pointers. You'll need to have an instance to call them.

Comment: Hi, thx for this express answer, this with 'static' seams to work (I do not receive any errors, I will need to try, since this is embedded ARM, so I will need to program device to check. Anyhow, THANKS :)

Comment: @gpufler You might find the [following reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) to be of use.

Comment: Unfortunately you will soon run into other problems. The first one is that inside `initMenu` you create *a new array* which is not the same as the member array, despite having the same name. And C++ requires than an array has a fixed constant size. `menuItem menuItems[];` is not possible as a class member. Instead `std::vector` is offered as a variable length container.

Comment: @BoPersson you are right, this will not work as I planned. I will figure out some other way. Maybe I even force it to work, but it will be mess after to maintain. Thank you all for support